# bibtex error, no bibliography attached

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm using pdflatex with texworks and vim latex-suite. I'm trying to append a bibliography to the document using

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Graph_bib}
```

and the .bib file formated as:

```
@inproceedings{Kovar:2008:MG:1401132.1401202,
 author = {Kovar, Lucas and Gleicher, Michael and Pighin, Fr\'{e}d\'{e}ric},
 title = {Motion graphs},
 booktitle = {ACM SIGGRAPH 2008 classes},
 series = {SIGGRAPH '08},
 year = {2008},
 location = {Los Angeles, California},
 pages = {51:1--51:10},
 articleno = {51},
 numpages = {10},
 url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1401132.1401202},
 doi = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1401132.1401202},
 acmid = {1401202},
 publisher = {ACM},
 address = {New York, NY, USA},
 keywords = {animation with constraints, motion capture, motion synthesis}
} 



@inproceedings{Witkin:1988:SC:54852.378507,
 author = {Witkin, Andrew and Kass, Michael},
 title = {Spacetime constraints},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the 15th annual conference on Computer graphics and interactive techniques},
 series = {SIGGRAPH '88},
 year = {1988},
 isbn = {0-89791-275-6},
 pages = {159--168},
 numpages = {10},
 url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/54852.378507},
 doi = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/54852.378507},
 acmid = {378507},
 publisher = {ACM},
 address = {New York, NY, USA},
 keywords = {animation, constraints}
}
```

... etc, however nothing appears when I compile the document to pdf. Any idea as to what's wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461905/compiling-latex-bib-source ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BibTeX only includes references you actually refer to in the text using the `\cite` command. To include all references in the bibliography file, you must issue the `\nocite` command:

```
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Graph_bib}
```